# How to add vehicles to a particular user in firebase through ionic typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Hi so I am creating a 'Gumtree for vehicles' and would like to add functionality which allows a logged in user to add vehicles to their profile, that becomes associated with their user, meaning that when I will be able to pull from firebase all the vehicles asscociated with their user. 
[Front End to ADD a vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq3AN.png)
[Front End to ADD a vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azg39.png)
Below is my code :

In the firebase.ts page:

```
  addVehicle(model, make, year, mileage, location) {
    this.afd.list('/vehicles/').push({model: model , make: make, year: year, mileage: mileage, location: location}
    );
  }
```

This is my addvehicle.html page

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>
      Add a Vehicle
    </ion-title>

  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding id="page23">
  <!--<form id="addAVehicle-form14">-->
    <ion-item color="none" id="addAVehicle-list-item39">
      <ion-icon name="car" item-left></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Model" [(ngModel)]="newVehicle"></ion-input>
      <ion-note item-right></ion-note>
      <!--<ion-icon name="car" item-left></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Model" [(ngModel)]="newVehicle2"></ion-input>
      <ion-note item-right></ion-note>-->
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item id="addAVehicle-select2">
      <ion-label>
        --make--
      </ion-label>
      <ion-select name="newVehicle2" [(ngModel)]="newVehicle2">
        <ion-option value="BMW">
          BMW
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Kia">
          Kia
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Mercedes-Benz">
          Mercedes-Benz
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Opel">
          Opel
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="VW">
          Volkswagen
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item id="addAVehicle-select3">
      <ion-label>
        --year of car--
      </ion-label>
      <ion-select name="newVehicle3" [(ngModel)]="newVehicle3">
        <ion-option value="2017">
          2017
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2016">
          2016
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2015">
          2015
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2014">
          2014
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2013">
          2013
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2012">
          2012
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2011">
          2011
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2010">
          2010
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2009">
          2009
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2008">
          2008
        </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2007">
          2007
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item id="addAVehicle-range2">
      <ion-label range-left>
        Mileage at registration
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Mileage" [(ngModel)]="newVehicle4"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item color="none" id="addAVehicle-list-item40">
      <ion-icon name="pin" item-left></ion-icon>
      Location
    </ion-item>

    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Location" [(ngModel)]="newVehicle5"></ion-input>
    <!--<button (click)="upload()" id="addAVehicle-button56" ion-button color="positive">
      Front view
    </button>-->

    <ion-content padding>
      <img src="{{pathForImage(lastImage)}}" style="width: 100%" [hidden]="lastImage === null">
      <h3 [hidden]="lastImage !== null">Please Select Image!</h3>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-buttons>
          <button ion-button icon-left (click)="presentActionSheet()">
            <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>Select Image
          </button>
          <button ion-button icon-left (click)="uploadImage()" [disabled]="lastImage === null">
            <ion-icon name="cloud-upload"></ion-icon>Upload
          </button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-footer>

    <button id="addAVehicle-button57" ion-button color="positive">
      Side view
    </button>
    <button id="addAVehicle-button58" ion-button color="positive">
      Rear view
    </button>
    <ion-item id="addAVehicle-toggle4">
      <ion-label>
        My car has defects
      </ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="positive" checked="false"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <!--<ion-item color="none" id="addAVehicle-list-item40">
      <ion-icon name="ionic" item-left></ion-icon>
      Item
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item color="none" id="addAVehicle-list-item41">
      <ion-icon name="ionic" item-left></ion-icon>
      Item
    </ion-item>-->

    <ion-item>
    <button ion-button color="positive" block (click)="addVehicle(); goToManage()">
    ADD VEHICLE
    </button>
    </ion-item>
  <!--</form>-->
</ion-content>
```

This is my firebase so far:

[enter image description here][3]

This is my addvehicle.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ActionSheetController, ToastController, Platform, LoadingController, Loading } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DriverProfilePage } from '../driver-profile/driver-profile';
import { BookingRequestPage } from '../booking-request/booking-request';
import { ClientProfilePage } from '../client-profile/client-profile';
import { MyBookingsPage } from '../my-bookings/my-bookings';
import { ResultsPage } from '../results/results';
import { ChecklistPage } from '../checklist/checklist';
import { ViewCarDetailsPage } from '../view-car-details/view-car-details';
import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { RentalsPage } from '../rentals/rentals';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
import { ManageCarsPage } from '../manage-cars/manage-cars';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseProvider } from './../../providers/firebase/firebase';

import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Transfer, TransferObject } from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-avehicle',
  templateUrl: 'add-avehicle.html'
})
export class AddAVehiclePage {

  vehicles: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  newVehicle = "";
  newVehicle2 = "";
  newVehicle3 = "";
  newVehicle4 = "";

  lastImage: string = null;
  loading: Loading;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider, private camera: Camera, private transfer: Transfer, private file: File, private filePath: FilePath, public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, public toastCtrl: ToastController, public platform: Platform, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.vehicles = this.firebaseProvider.getVehicleList();
  }

  public presentActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: 'Select Image Source',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Load from Library',
          handler: () => {
            this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Use Camera',
          handler: () => {
            this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel'
        }
      ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }

  public takePicture(sourceType) {

    var options = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
      if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
        this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
        .then(filePath => {
          let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
          this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
        });
      } else {
        var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
      }
    }, (err) => {
      this.presentToast('Error selecting image.');
    });
  }

  private createFileName() {
    var d = new Date(),
    n = d.getTime(),
    newFileName = n + ".jpg";
    return newFileName;
  }

  private copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName) {
    this.file.copyFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(success => {
      this.lastImage = newFileName;
    }, error => {
      this.presentToast('Error while storing file.');
    });
  }

  private presentToast(text) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: text,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  public pathForImage(img) {
    if (img === null) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return cordova.file.dataDirectory + img;
    }
  }

  public uploadImage() {
    // Destination URL
    var url = "http://yoururl/upload.php";

    // File for Upload
    var targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.lastImage);

    // File name only
    var filename = this.lastImage;

    var options = {
      fileKey: "file",
      fileName: filename,
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
      params : {'fileName': filename}
    };

    const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Uploading...',
    });
    this.loading.present();

    // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
    fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
      this.loading.dismissAll()
      this.presentToast('Image succesful uploaded.');
    }, err => {
      this.loading.dismissAll()
      this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
    });
  }

  addVehicle(){
    this.firebaseProvider.addVehicle(this.newVehicle,this.newVehicle2,this.newVehicle3,this.newVehicle4);
  }

  goToDriverProfile(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(DriverProfilePage);
  }goToBookingRequest(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(BookingRequestPage);
  }goToClientProfile(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(ClientProfilePage);
  }goToMyBookings(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(MyBookingsPage);
  }goToResults(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(ResultsPage);
  }goToChat(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(ChatPage);
  }goToChecklist(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(ChecklistPage);
  }goToViewCarDetails(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(ViewCarDetailsPage);
  }goToHome(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }goToLogin(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
  }goToRentals(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(RentalsPage);
  }goToSignup(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(SignupPage);
  }goToManage(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(ManageCarsPage);

  };

  }
```

Comment: Basically, how do I code where the vehicle should go ( to which user in the firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another field to your user (like birthday, email etc.) named "vehicles" and then add all the ids of vehicles he has selected in that.
So basically your firebase database will look something like this:

```
userProfile: {
              user_key: {
                          "email": "user_email",
                          "vehicles": {
                                       vehicle_key_1: true,
                                       vehicle_key_2: true
                                      }
                        }
             }
```

In your addVehicle function, pass the key of user adding vehicles. Then change the function like this:

```
addVehicle(user_key, model, make, year, mileage, location) {
this.afd.list('/userProfile/user_key/vehicles').push({model: model , make: make, year: year, mileage: mileage, location: location}
);
```

}

Comment: But how do i make sure these vehicles are going there, should i change the path here: addVehicle(model, make, year, mileage, location) {
    this.afd.list('/vehicles/').push({model: model , make: make, year: year, mileage: mileage, location: location}
    );
  }

Comment: Please re-read my question, also edited it. Included wireframes

Comment: The 'user_key' variable, how do you target the specific key of the user, e.g. 0St43582934...

Comment: You can save that key somewhere when that user logs into the app or something. What happens when a user logs into your app?

Comment: They reach a landing page

Comment: Is theer a way i can upload my project

Comment: That won't be necessary. Just get the user key of the logged in user from the userProfile table in Firebase database.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please accept the answer? :)

Comment: Done can you also help with my other question please

Comment: Yeah sure. What is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461682/how-to-add-vehicles-to-a-particular-user-in-firebase-through-ionic-typescript/45462123?noredirect=1#comment77933267_45462123